# Excel VBA button to export range to desktop regardless of user does not work on other computers?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA macro button to export a range of cells as a CSV file to the desktop. This file will be downloaded on multiple computers so I want the macro to save to the desktop regardless of which computer it is downloaded on.

```
Sub seetest()

    Const CSVDATA = "B1:IG2"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, filename As String
    
    filename = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
               "\Desktop\Labels " & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".csv"
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With Workbooks.Add(1)
        ws.Range(CSVDATA).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .SaveAs filename, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
       
    MsgBox CSVDATA & " exported to " & filename, vbInformation

End Sub
```

This is the code for my macro and when I do it on my laptop, the computer that I created the files on, it works; however, when any of my coworkers do it the CSV file isn't auto saved to the desktop but instead it is opened with Excel and these errors populate. I could just change the directions so that instead of just pressing the export button that they press it, save the file themselves, and then use it but I want to automate this as much as possible. Any ideas why I receive these errors on other laptops but not mine?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the Desktop is always in the directory `"C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ "`? Does `Environ("Username")` return the username? The error message is saying that it cannot access the file because the directory you want to save it do does not exist.

Comment: @Storax: Sorry just saw your comment. If you would like to put that as an answer, I will delete my answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: No problem. I am fine. I am not here for the rep ;-)

Comment: @Storax Yes I understand. I did not mean it from the rep point of view. It was more of you suggested it first :)

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 reasons that I can think of.

The desktop path for that user may be different. So do not hardcode that path. Try this.

```
Dim CurUserDesktopPath As String
CurUserDesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\"

Dim filename As String
filename = CurUserDesktopPath & "Labels " & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".csv"

MsgBox filename
```

If this doesn't work then it is possible that the user doesn't have the *Rights* to save to that location.

Comment: I edited the code to look like this:

Sub seetest()

    Dim CurUserDesktopPath As String
CurUserDesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\"

Dim filename As String
filename = CurUserDesktopPath & "Labels " & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".csv"

MsgBox filename

End Sub

Is this correct? It is not working to export to the desktop, unfortunately

Comment: No it is not. This only creates the filename. You have to incorporate this into your code to save the file.